# Normalization around the nominal value while avoiding to get too big results

Tags: data, normalization

Lets say we measured a signal N times. Each measurement contains T time instance. For example for N=4 measurements and T=5 time instances the data matrix is as follows:

```
% N measurements for T time instance   
Data =      [-1  0   1.5  1.8 
             0   -3  1.9  -1.5
             1.9 1.1 0.9  1
             0   1.7 -1.3 0
             0.6 1.3 -1.8 0]
```

On the other hand, we know that the sum of the signal values over T time instance should be `X`(Nominal value).
Therefore, we can normalize each measurements at each time instance as follows:

```
Normalized_Data = (Data .- X/4)./abs(X/4)
```

The above normalization works fine as long as X is not around zero. Basically, when a `Dij` (The jth measurement of the signal for ith instance) is equal to its expected (basically X/ size(X)) the normalized value is 0, when its bellow/above the expected, it is negative/positive respectively.  However, when the given nominal value (X) is around zero, the Normalized_Data gets too large. 
Is there any suggestion for a normalization method that avoids this issue?